# When I call the session in a register file, Its lifetime is not 1440 seconds

Tags: php, session

I searched about the default lifetime of a session and I understood that it is `1440` seconds. But in the following `register` file when the user can register in the database, for the user makes the `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;`. But  Its lifetime is perpetual and not `1440` seconds.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {echo "you are logged";}
else {
check the username and password and the characters and if they are correct, insert to the database and if successful, So create the following session variables that it gets the username value 
 $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you try a `phpinfo();` in your code and see if it is indeed configured as you think it is. Perhaps it was overridden in your configuration

Answer (score 0):

Check out php.ini the value set for session.gc_maxlifetime is the ID lifetime in seconds.

I believe the default is 1440 seconds (24 mins). Or try this:

```
// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 24 minutes
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1440);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 24 minutes
session_set_cookie_params(1440);

session_start(); // ready to go!
```